# Implementing separation of concerns via MVC

Tags: java, mvc, separation-of-concerns

I'm creating a question to see if my understanding of MVC separation is correct, I haven't been able to find a clear answer anywhere online. So is this the right way to implement it (in Java):

I would have 3 .java files, one each for Model, Controller, View.
I would put all the classes related to Model in the Model.java like so:

```
//Model.java {
    public class Model

    //class fields

    public Model();

    public ModelClassA();

    public ModelClassB();

    public ModelClassC();
    }
```

With the ModelClasses being any class that I consider belonging to the Model. Is it correct to have the classes within the Model Class, as I have read that nested classes should be avoided where possible.

Comment: Obviously I would implement View and Controller as I have done with Model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are mixing some terminology here. Java nested classes is not the same as a model having a property which is also a model.

If your concern is whether to have a model whose properties are other models- then this is OK (as long as the models are not nested classes in terms of a Java nested class). It is a good way to encapsulate logic and reduce code repetition.

Consider for instance an `Order` model (as an e-commerce order) and a `Customer` model. They both may need to use address information, so the order will have a `ShippingAddress` property, and the `Customer` would have an `Address` property. Both can be of the same type (same java class) and be represented by an additional model, say an `Address` model.

A nested Java class is a different thing. This is a class that is defined within another Java class, and in some cases a nested class may have special interactions allowed with the "hosting" class. You'd better check [the Java documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html) which describes the Java nested classes, and the difference between static and non-static nested classes.

Comment: +1 for talking about both aspects (models saved in model vs. model nested in model). I would only add that it is absolutely ok to have nested classes in certain situations, it does not need "to be avoided where possible"

Comment: Thanks, I see what you're saying and I'll read up on it.

Comment: @avalancha, I agree that you can have a model that is a nested class, but as long as it is deliberately seeked by the developer. I was probably more strict in my post in order to keep both aspects separate, as the OP seemed confusing them